# I did it correct, but it didn't work line 4 : TypeError it's saying

Tags: python

```
class Animal:

    def __init__(self, birthType="Unknown", appearence="Unknown", blooded="Unknown"):
        self.birthType = birthType
        self.appearence = appearence
        self.blooded = blooded

    @property
    def birthType(self):
        return self.__birthType

    @birthType.setter
    def birthType(self):
        self.__birthType = birthType

    @property
    def appearence(self):
        return self.__appearence

    @appearence.setter
    def apppearence(self):
        self.__appearence = appearence

    @property
    def blooded(self):
        return self.__blooded

    @blooded.setter
    def blooded(self):
        self.__blooded = blooded

    def __str__(self):
        return "A {} is {} it is {} it is {]".format(type(self).__name__, self.birthType, self.appearence, self.blooded)


class Mammal(Animal):

    def __init__(self, birthType="born alive", appearence="hair or fur", blooded="warm blooded", nurseYoung=True):
        Animal.__init__(self, birthType, appearence, blooded)

        self.__nurseYoung = nurseYoung

        @property
        def nurseYoung(self):
            return self.__nurseYoung

        @nurseYoung.setter
        def nurseYoung(self):
            self.nurseYoung = nurseYoung

        def __str__(self):
            return super().__str__() + " and it is {} they nurse their young".format(self.nurseYoung)


class Reptile(Animal):
    def __init__(self, birthType="born in an egg or born alive", appearence="dry scales", blooded="cold blooded"):
        Animal.__init__(self, birthType, appearence, blooded)


def main():
    animal1 = Animal("born alive")

    print(animal1.birthType)

main()
```

Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/td/tmp/e/test.py", line 65, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/td/tmp/e/test.py", line 61, in main
    animal1 = Animal("born alive")
  File "/home/td/tmp/e/test.py", line 4, in __init__
    self.birthType = birthType
TypeError: birthType() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Comment: Can you, please, expand a little: what are you trying to do, what's the full error message, traceback etc.

Comment: If the error is near line 4 then you dont need to add any of the irrelevant code below it

Comment: There are no line numbers here, so please be more clear in the future.

Comment: IDK what is the cause of the specific error message, but I can see one problem: You are inconsistent in naming your instance variables. In one place you say `self.birthType`, but in another place you say `self.__birthType`. Those are two different names, therefore two different variables.

Comment: You're missing a parameter in each of your property setters. Check any working property setter code.

Comment: I ran your code and added the traceback to your question. If its not right, change it to what you are seeing.

Comment: As an aside, since these properties don't do anything besides get and set, they shouldn't be properties at all. Properties are only needed if you plan to do some sort of manipulation of the assignee.

Comment: This looks a lot like Java written in Python. The names don't conform to the [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and those getters and setters are superfluous. You might want to switch to a different tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing __underscores for the members on line 4-6

```
def __init__(self, birthType="Unknown", appearence="Unknown", blooded="Unknown"):
    self.__birthType = birthType
    self.__appearence = appearence
    self.__blooded = blooded
```

Above works if you want to be setting your private members at the constructor without using your selfdefined setter for it first.

In case of you would want to set the member values as they are you should use the same line of code that defines the setter.

The other option is to simply use your setter itself, but that is faulty as well, as @khelwood pointed out in an [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69214614/9660245)

Comment: Can you [edit] the answer and explain why it needs underscores? And why double underscores? AFAIK a single underscore indicates a private field in Python, but that doesn't mean every field has to be private and start with an underscore. Double underscores are used for reserved (function!) names like `__init__`.

Comment: The underlying problem is that the property setters are written wrong. If they were right, the init would be fine as is.

Comment: @Robert - I agree, but leading double underscore are for "private" data. That is, it will be mangled with the class name by python. Its normally used to protect internal data from subclasses, but that's only rarely usefule.

Comment: @khelwood - interesting point but if your setters need information from the initialized object, they may not be usable in init.

Comment: @tdelaney Ah, right, namespace mangling. I forgot. Good point!

Comment: I think that setting member values directly in init is implicitly stating that you only set members without any more fluff like calling other functions from inside that hideous setter

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: As @khelwood pointed out, it's **not** the double underscore attribute names that are causing the problem regardless of whether it's appropriate to be using them or not. The problem is the setters were not written correctly. His and my own answer show how to do it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Each of your property setters is missing a parameter.

Where you have this:

```
@birthType.setter
def birthType(self):
    self.__birthType = birthType
```

You want something like this:

```
@birthType.setter
def birthType(self, value):
    self.__birthType = value
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing the setters correctly, they each need to have a `value` argument as shown below. You also misspelled `appearence` in `def apppearence(self):`.

````
class Animal:

    def __init__(self, birthType="Unknown", appearence="Unknown", blooded="Unknown"):
        self.birthType = birthType
        self.appearence = appearence
        self.blooded = blooded

    @property
    def birthType(self):
        return self.__birthType

    @birthType.setter
    def birthType(self, value):
        self.__birthType = value

    @property
    def appearence(self):
        return self.__appearence

    @appearence.setter
    def appearence(self, value):
        self.__appearence = value

    @property
    def blooded(self):
        return self.__blooded

    @blooded.setter
    def blooded(self, value):
        self.__blooded = value

    def __str__(self):
        return "A {} is {} it is {} it is {]".format(type(self).__name__, self.birthType, self.appearence, self.blooded)


class Mammal(Animal):

    def __init__(self, birthType="born alive", appearence="hair or fur", blooded="warm blooded", nurseYoung=True):
        Animal.__init__(self, birthType, appearence, blooded)

        self.__nurseYoung = nurseYoung

        @property
        def nurseYoung(self):
            return self.__nurseYoung

        @nurseYoung.setter
        def nurseYoung(self):
            self.nurseYoung = nurseYoung

        def __str__(self):
            return super().__str__() + " and it is {} they nurse their young".format(self.nurseYoung)


class Reptile(Animal):
    def __init__(self, birthType="born in an egg or born alive", appearence="dry scales", blooded="cold blooded"):
        Animal.__init__(self, birthType, appearence, blooded)


def main():
    animal1 = Animal("born alive")

    print(animal1.birthType)

main()
```
````